# Editing Code to save files as KMZ

Tags: pyqgis, kmz

I want to edit the code I have below to save vector files as vectors and also save vector files as KMZs.

The code I have does a mass save to my temporary folder but only for rasters.

```
myDir = r'C:\temp'
layers = layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
for layer in layers:
   extent = layer.extent()
   width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
   renderer = layer.renderer()
   provider=layer.dataProvider()
   crs = layer.crs().toWkt() 
   pipe.set(provider.clone())
   pipe.set(renderer.clone())
   file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter("%s\\%s.tif" %(myDir, layer.name() ))
   file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                       width,
                       height,
                       extent,
                       layer.crs())
   print "%s\\%s.tif" %(myDir, layer.name() )
```

Comment: I'm not sure if QGIS supports writing .kmz files (which are zipped .kml files). But you can certainly save your vector layers to .kmz files.

Comment: What i've been doing is just right-clicking and save-as to KML file.  I wondered if there was a faster way to do it without merging the vector layers.  Sometimes I have upwards of 50 layers to save.

Comment: So you just want to convert all loaded layers into .kml files?

Comment: Yes.  And also I want to save the vectors as vectors so I don't need to do it  one at a time.  I figured I could edit the "pipe" variable to work with vectors but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Your code only affects rasters, most of it will either not work or is not necessary for vector layers. There is the **Batch Save Layers** plugin which allows you to save all loaded vector layers into KML files. Or you could check this post: [Bulk file convertor QGIS plugin/program](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200899/bulk-file-convertor-qgis-plugin-program)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to edit the code I currently have to work with vectors instead of rasters.  That should be useful, thank you.

Comment: In the post I linked to in my comment is some code I posted which saves all loaded layers in QGIS into .kml files. Perhaps you can test it :)